# Restricting maxdate and mindate of second datepicker onchanging first datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have two datepickers one for startDate and other for endDate which are initially set to current.

Now when I change startDate I want the 
1. endDate should have minDate as selected date and 
2. maxDate will be 2 months from the selected.

Step 1 is working but I have problem with step2 .
my current code looks like this:

`$( "#from" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
            $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", "+2M" );
        }
    }).datepicker("setDate", "0");`

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate), you are actually setting the `maxDate` options 2 months from **today**:

> String: Relative dates must contain value and period pairs; valid periods are `"y"` for years, `"m"` for months, `"w"` for weeks, and `"d"` for days. **For example, `"+1m +7d"` represents one month and seven days from today**.

Comment: Ya i know that but how should i change it on the basis of seleted date not from today's date

Comment: Well... just do the math! :) Look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for the Date class reference